# Unable to extract using tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Tags: tar

Unable to extract using tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Log4j2 download [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html)

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/logging/log4j/2.17.1/apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz
```

Download key -

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dist/logging/KEYS
```

Download signature

```
wget https://downloads.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.17.1/apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz.asc



root@ip-172-31-18-202:/tmp# gpg --import KEYS
gpg: key 12B287580C7C4F05: "Mark Dwayne Womack <mwomack@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 266191C37C037D42: "Yoav Shapira <yoavs@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key BE16C95D2E114322: "Curt Arnold <carnold@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key D3EC499070C9C3D0: "carnold@apache.org (CODE SIGNING KEY) <carnold@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key B35E96D747C4113E: "Jacob Kjome <hoju@visi.com>" not changed
gpg: key 0DD1EC2A914A4D28: "Nicko Cadell <nicko@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 3595395EB3D8E1BA: "Ralph Goers (CODE SIGNING KEY) <rgoers@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 86E02C5A42196CA8: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 86E02C5A42196CA8: "Christian Grobmeier (Apache Codesigning) <grobmeier@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key C140F70BED446286: "Nicholas Scott Williams (For signing NWTS Java Code) <nicholas@nicholaswilliams.net>" not changed
gpg: key 6C45F247A303D55F: "Nicholas Scott Williams (For ASF Code Signing Purposes Only) <nickwilliams@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key C264130FA5CC90DB: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key C264130FA5CC90DB: "Christian Grobmeier <cg@grobmeier.de>" not changed
gpg: key F6492CB4778C3033: "Thorsten Schöning <tschoening@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 1E4B1D05B095DD52: "Robert Middleton <robert.middleton@rm5248.com>" not changed
gpg: key D7C92B70FA1C814D: 19 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D7C92B70FA1C814D: "Matt Sicker (Apache Software Foundation) <mattsicker@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 47B1D6AD0E682C9C: "Davyd McColl <davydm@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: key 17745EF55497A907: 6 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 17745EF55497A907: "Dominik Psenner <dpsenner@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key D37D4387C9BD368E: "Volkan Yazici (vy) <volkan@yazi.ci>" not changed
gpg: key 1E6F62D27A7A9A1E: "Carter Kozak (YubiKey 5C NFC 17031888) <ckozak@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: key 85917FEBF6651A65: "Carter Kozak (YubiKey 5C NFC 17031890) <ckozak@apache.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 19
gpg:              unchanged: 19



root@ip-172-31-18-202:/tmp# gpg --verify apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz'
gpg: Signature made Mon Dec 27 23:29:29 2021 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key 9D0A56AAA0D60E0C0C7DCCC0B4C70893B62BABE8
gpg:                issuer "mattsicker@apache.org"
gpg: BAD signature from "Matt Sicker (Apache Software Foundation) <mattsicker@apache.org>" [unknown]


root@ip-172-31-18-202:/tmp# tar -xvf apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz
    gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
    tar: Child returned status 1
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: If you use `file apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz` you will likely see that your `wget` command actually downloaded an HTML document

Comment: yes you are right, I've noticed that.

Comment: Use `grep -i http apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz` you'll see the actual download link. Look at the file with `less apache-log4j-2.17.1-bin.tar.gz` (HTML files are text files, no matter what they're named) to see if there is an error message.